# Check if Date is in Range

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date range suppose 2000-01-01 to 2021-06-01. I want to check whether a particular month with a given year falls in this range or not (E.g., month = March and year = 2021) using JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? One that you're quite happy about after your extensive research on Google? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Create a reusable function `isDateInRange` that accepts your three date Strings arguments.
Than you can simply compare your [Date Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using the needed operands:

```js
const isDateInRange = (date, from, to) => {
  const d = new Date(date);
  const f = new Date(from);
  const t = new Date(to);
  return (d >= f && d < t); 
};

console.log(isDateInRange("2001-01-31",   "2000-01-01", "2021-06-01")) // true
console.log(isDateInRange("2050-01-01",   "2000-01-01", "2021-06-01")) // false
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution passing month and year (not a date) as you requested.

```
const lowerRange = new Date('2000-01-01');
const upperRange = new Date('2021-06-01');

// If month and year are numbers
const monthYearInRange = (year, month) => {
  if (typeof month !== 'number') throw new Error('Month should be number');
  if (typeof year !== 'number') throw new Error('Year should be number');

  // We do this to make sure it is 2 chars.
  const mth = month < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;

  // Set it to first of the month
  const checkVal = new Date(`${year}-${mth}-01`);
  if (isNaN(checkVal)) throw new Error(`Year: ${year} and Month: ${month} are not valid.`);

  return checkVal <= upperRange && checkVal >= lowerRange;
}

console.log(monthYearInRange(2000, 2)); // true
console.log(monthYearInRange(2030, 2)); // false
console.log(monthYearInRange(2021, 6)); // true
console.log(monthYearInRange(2021, 10)); // false
```

Just a note on this solution - because ultimately we convert the year/month into a date, when doing this we have to instantiate the date using the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`. If `checkVal` gets instantiated with a month that is a single character (`1` instead of `01`) it will still work in most cases - but you will get edge cases breaking because the `Date()` constructor will add timezone values to the date.

Update: Added NaN check - per @RobG

Comment: Note that `typeof NaN == 'number'`. :-) Consider `let date = new Date(year, month - 1)` will create a date for the first of the month. If the values are not valid, then *date* will be an invalid date and any equality test will return false.

Answer (score -1):

```
I tried the following approach and it worked:

function isBetween(n, a, b) {
    return (n - a) * (n - b) <= 0
 }

var startDate = '2021-03-15';
var endDate = '2021-06-01';
var checkFor = '2021-05-31';

D_1 = startDate.split("-");
D_2 = endDate.split("-");
D_3 = checkFor.split("-");
//console.log(D_1+" "+D_2+" "+D_3);

var startNumber = D_1[0]*100 + D_1[1];
var endNumber = D_2[0]*100 + D_2[1];
var checkNumber = D_3[0]*100 + D_3[1];

 var check = isBetween(checkNumber, startNumber, endNumber);
 console.log(check);
```